# C++ odbc Query not actually inserting record

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm currently attempting to build a simple C++ program to insert a record into a MS Sql Server database. The code executes and return codes indicate that things technically worked, yet no record is actually getting inserted to the database. I'm at a lose as to what might be causing the issue. Driver maybe?

Originally I intended to use prepared statements and avoid any string copying, but I couldn't seem to get those to work properly. So, to test if anything would happen at all, I build a query as below. Not the best approach and not my intended approach but I can't even seem to get a record inserted to the db.

Return codes do not indicate problems with the connection (please note, I've changed the actual connection information) or even the execution of the query, which leans me towards perhaps needing a commit? Also why I might be inclined to think it is the driver. Thoughts?

Here is the code:

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <rpc.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")
```

And testCamel2Db.cpp

```
// testCamel2Db.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

INT connectDb(VOID);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    connectDb();
    return 0;
}

INT connectDb (VOID)
{
    RETCODE rc; //ODBC return code
    HENV henv;  //environment handle
    HSTMT hstmt;//statement handle
    HDBC hdbc;  //connection handle

    SQLAllocEnv(&henv);
    SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);

    rc = SQLDriverConnect(
        hdbc,
        NULL,
        (unsigned char*)"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server.name.edu,3433;DATABASE=camel2;UID=username;PWD=password;",
        SQL_NTS,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    if ((rc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    {
        //error handling here
        std::cout << "no connection created.";
        return 1;
    }


    //create a uuid
    UUID uuid;
    UuidCreate(&uuid);
    unsigned char* uuidStr;
    UuidToStringA(&uuid,&uuidStr);
    INT quotedUuidSize = strlen((char*)uuidStr) + 2;
    char* quotedUuidStr = new char[quotedUuidSize +1];
    memset(quotedUuidStr, 0, sizeof(char) * quotedUuidSize + 1);
    strcat(quotedUuidStr, "'");
    strcat(quotedUuidStr, (char*)uuidStr);
    strcat(quotedUuidStr, "'");

    //admin_user variable
    LPSTR adminUser;
    adminUser = "'Active Directory'";

    //build a query
    LPSTR sql = "INSERT cw_ResetCheck (ResetUID, AdminUser ) values (";
    INT queryStrSize = strlen(sql) + strlen((char*)quotedUuidStr) + strlen(adminUser) + 2;
    char* queryStr = new char[queryStrSize + 1];
    memset(queryStr, 0, sizeof(char) * (queryStrSize + 1));
    strcat(queryStr,sql);
    strcat(queryStr,(char*)quotedUuidStr);
    strcat(queryStr,",");
    strcat(queryStr,adminUser);
    strcat(queryStr,")");

    std::cout << queryStr << "\n";

    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hdbc,&hstmt);

    std::cout << uuidStr;

    rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)queryStr, SQL_NTS);

    if ((rc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (rc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    {
        std::cout << "query failed";
        return 1;
    } 
    else
    {
        std::cout << "uid created: ";
        std::cout << uuidStr;
    }

    //close database
    SQLFreeStmt(hstmt,SQL_DROP);
    SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
    SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try turning on auto commit, or run a select statement at the end of your function to see if the row is in the database (or try using SSMS and NOLOCK before closing the connection)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. When I have a moment I'll try turning on auto commits and see if that changes the situation.

Comment: So I enabled auto commits and I'm still in the same situation. Going to investigate SSMS and NOLOCK

Comment: One option is also to use profiler, to see what statements are actually being executed

Comment: Okay, now this is very strange. It is showing me (with a select query in the above code) records that I don't see in Sql Server Studio.  What have I done?

Comment: I dont think this is the cause of the error, but does it help if you replace SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_DROP); with SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE); ? Note that SQL_DROP is deprecated.

And next, I would try to add a SQLEndTran(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, SQL_COMMIT); before the call to SQLDisconnect() - just to see if it forcing a commit would help. Although I dont think that is the cause of the problem, as Autocommit should be enabled by default.

Comment: Okay. Here's the nuts and bolts of what I did wrong here. First, using the profiler was a huge help so thank you for the suggestion. Also, thank you both for pointing out the nuances in how odbc works (and alas doesn't work) in c++ as it helped me narrow my troubleshooting. I ended up creating records in another instance of the Sql Server as I had the port in the connection string incorrect. So, it turns out the code was working after all. Also, good to know that autocommits are on be default. Thanks guys.